# Get the failure reason from a mail in outlook

Tags: email, outlook, lotus

I am doing some automation on outlook mail box, previously it was lotus notes.So i am looking for equivalent properties in outlook. The lotus notes mail items has a [item](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ITEMS_PROPERTY.html) named `FAILUREREASON` which has the details about why the email is failed such as delivery failure reason etc. This item will be available when the mail is a delivery failure email. So when i loop through mails in inbox i can recognize which mail is a delivery failure email in inbox and which is actual required mail to be processed. But in outlook [MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx) object i didn't find any option to get it. I searched for any solutuion but not able to find any. We can search subject for words such as 'failure' but it's not good approach. Can anyone know the property that i need to look or any other approach for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard bounce or undeliverable emails are received in Outlook as special items using the `"REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR"` message class and are available as a `ReportItem` object in the Outlook Object Model.  You can also read the mail header information via the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W` MAPI property on any kind of email.

One way of retrieving the value is by using `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")`

Comment: May i know the url GetProperty method that need to be used? Also where i can find the list of schema urls.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The best way to find the DASL name for a MAPI property is to use OutlookSpy.  You can also construct the DASL name if you know the namespace and property type. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815492.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc979184.aspx

Comment: I fetched the property and found that there exists a node "X-Failed-Recipients" . So do i need to find for this string and if exists do i need to consider it as a delivery failed mail? Is it a good approach ? Also how can i get failure reason? (Example of failure reason: Your message wasn't delivered to ******@gmail.com because the address couldn't be found. Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again. )

Comment: Yes, you'll have to parse the strings in PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS manually. AFAIK all delivery error messages should be stored in there, as well as in the email body

Comment: Keep in mind that if the NDR was generated by your Exchange Server, `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS ` will **not** contain any error info, it is only stored in the recipient table.

Answer (score 0):

`ReportItem` object in the Outlook Object Model (not related to the `MailItem` object) exposes NDR information through the `ReportItem.Body` property. On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only) the properties are stored in the recipient table - you can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, go to the GetRecipientTable tab:

[image]

For the `MailItem` objects, you can access that information using `Recipient.PropetyAccessor.GetProperty` method, but `ReportItem` object does not expose the `Recipients` collection (unlike the `MailItem` object). In theory, you can change the `MessageClass` property to `"IPM.Note"`, remember the value of the `EntryID` property, save the NDR, release the original, reopen the item as a regular `MailItem` object by calling `Namespace.GetItemFromID`, and then read the data from the recipient table. But that means modifying the original NDR (its modification time will change etc.).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), its [RDOReportItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOReportItem.htm) object (derived from the `RDOMail` object) exposes the `Recipients` collection. You can reopen Outlook's NDR in Redemption by creating an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object and calling `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` method. The recipient properties will be accessible using `RDORecipient.Fields[]`.